# No Bean for ResourceServerTokenServices found - Spring-Security-Oauth2

Tags: java, spring, rest, oauth-2.0, spring-boot

I'm building a sample project with spring-boot just to learn something about it.
Specifically, i'm trying to integrate spring-security-oauth2 module to secure my rest services.
I followed this sample project that shows a very simple in-memory login system: https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth
It works, and this is good.
Anyway, when I tried to integrate it in my application i get the following exception:

```
...    
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not wire ResourceServerTokenServices: please create a bean definition and mark it as @Primary.
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration.resolveTokenServices(ResourceServerConfiguration.java:170) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration.configure(ResourceServerConfiguration.java:140) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:199) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:283) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:68) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$71f30f65.init(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:367) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:320) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:92) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$373175f.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$3(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$373175f$$FastClassByCGLIB$$ffddf00e.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:326) ~[spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$373175f.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
```

From what i know, the DefaultTokenServices implementation of ResourceServerTokenServices should be ready to use, without further implementation (at leas for this simple scenario). Am I wrong?

The following snippets are my oauth configuration classes:

**AuthorizationServerConfiguration:**

```
@Configuration @EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

    @Inject
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Inject
    private ResourceIdProvider resourceIdProvider;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
            .tokenStore(tokenStore)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
            .inMemory()
            .withClient("clientapp")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
            .authorities("USER")
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .resourceIds(this.resourceIdProvider.getResourceId())
            .secret("123456");
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(this.tokenStore);
        return tokenServices;
    } }
```

**ResourceServerConfigurationImpl:**

```
@Configuration @EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfigurationImpl extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private ResourceIdProvider resourceIdProvider;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(this.resourceIdProvider.getResourceId());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/rest/user")
            .authenticated();
    } }
```

**InMemoryWebSecurityConfiguration:**

```
@Configuration @EnableWebSecurity
public class InMemoryWebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("roy")
            .password("spring")
            .roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

Can somebody help me get this running?
If you need more code let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a hint in the error message (mark your token services as `@Primary`). Did you try that?

Comment: I didn't... `@Primary` did the trick, thanks. I can't believe i just needed this. If you copy this comment as an answer i'll be happy to mark as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a hint in the error message (mark your token services as @Primary). That should work. Also (I think) you can just inject a `TokenStore` into the `ResourceServerConfigurer` and share it with the rest of the context.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem since 2.0.5-RELEASE version, it didn't happen on 2.0.4-BUILD-SNAPSHOT. I opened a issue here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/342